# Not Resize the Subviews in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios8, ios9

I am trying to resize the view but not working,

I have UIView in CustomCell, its working in iphone 5S but when i check in iPhone6 or iphone6+ simulator than its not changing the size of UIViews.

cell.ViewImgWithOption.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0, WIDTH,60);

Above code working in 320 size screen Width but not working in 375 or 414 size screen Width.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

try this one hope it will work.

cell.ViewImgWithOption.frame= CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width,60);